# Периодическое зависание windows 10

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, железо, ssd

Во время работы на компьютере он частенько просто "замирает", движение мышкой осуществляется (если часто ей не щелкать), но ни на что не реагирует, а потом просыпается и резко воспроизводит все действия, которые во время зависания были произведены. Что происходит? Компьютер работает не на полную мощность. Думал сначала причина в Касперском, но после отключения зависания не пропали. Думаю может причина в SSD. Компьютер сам собирал, может железо конфликтует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался и как решали проблему?

**UPDATE**

В играх зависания нет. Зависает только когда я работаю с окнами.

Answer (score 1):

Подвисания могут быть связны и с CPU или RAM советую произвести полную проверку с помощью любого удобного Вам бенчмарка, он поможет выявить просадки в загрузках процессора. И вообще не мешало бы больше информации ) что за железо, декстоп или ноутбук ?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на проблемы с обращениями к диску. Проверь его на smart и потестируй, не будет ли провалов. Ещё погляди в диспетчере задач, не грузит ли что диск, по графикам удобней смотреть или в монитор ресурсов посмотреть. Если десктоп, можно сразу поменять sata кабель на другой.
Так же может тормозить из-за архивации или индексации диска.